# Is it okay to try out a FAQ tag?

Tags: discussion

Despite the fact that this site is intended "for experts by experts" the truth is that we often get a lot of questions that revolve around what many of us would consider to be very fundamental topics -

- The Trinity
- The Development of the Canon
- The Historicity of Scripture (e.g. Creation / Evolution)
- The Virgin Birth and other Miracles.

(And this list should get bigger)

I'd like to try out adding a [faq](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag for those questions which garner answers that help provide a good intro level understanding of a topic.

I also took the liberty of tagging several questions in this way.

Is this ok?  Does anyone else support this idea?

Comment: Why don't we do it on Meta!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This sort of thing qualifies as a [meta-tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) which are strongly discouraged across most of the SE network and I don't see a good case for them here. Introducing this particular tag is likely to produce inter-doctrinal squabbles as if the site itself were supporting a particular view on a particular issue.

If people are interested in finding out something about, for example, the trinity, they are welcome to look though the [trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity) tag and even [sort it by votes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity?sort=votes) to find questions that people found most interesting or useful. Additionally there is a question [sort method called "frequent"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) which sorts by the number of incoming links to a question. This works for tags as well, so you could get [the questions tagged trinity and frequently linked](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity?sort=frequent).

Note: Please don't mass edit the tag out either. Once it becomes clear through a few votes or voices here that I'm not just speaking for myself, we can remove the tag en mass without bumping all the questions. Again.

Comment: Understood. Sorry!